# How do I load dynamic data onclick into a map infowindow using Ammap?

Tags: javascript, ammap

I've built an Ammap that displays data in an infowindow based on which continent gets clicked, and I'm really close to where I want to get, with the exception of 2 things:

1. Upon map load, the first click displays the correct data, but that data remains in the infowindow - clicking other regions takes no effect. The objective is to clear the infowindow and display data from the region clicked last.
2. After onclick, the region's color changes accordingly. But if you hover above it again, the color disappears. How do I make the onclick color 'stick'?

I believe I made the error when I commented these few lines out - the original code had enabled multiple-area select, and the map I had in mind should only allow single area select.

```js
        //event.mapObject.showAsSelected = !event.mapObject.showAsSelected;
        
    //map.returnInitialColor(event.mapObject);
```

Please see the working pen here and let me know if you can help: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPeXor

Thanks in advance for any help!